# MySQL functions don't load when using custom PHP.ini on windows server

Tags: php, mysql, function

php.ini on the server loads mysql functions, but as i have to use a custom php.ini on the site root, after adding the file the server is not loading mysql function.

without the custom php5.ini file mysql functions and their values appear in the phpinfo() but when i create the custom php5.ini on the site root and run the phpinfo() mysql functions and their values do not appear on that page?

Need help.  thanks.

Comment: do you have a link to the phpinfo() pages?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "mysql functions and their values do not appear [in phpinfo()]"?

I know what mysql functions are - but they don't appear in phpinfo() at any time. Function values...? Do you mean the mysql related ini settings? If so then you've probably not declared the mysql extension in the ini file.

Something like...

```
extension_dir="C:/php5/ext/"
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

for MSWindows. For everything else, something like:

```
extension_dir="/usr/lib/php/modules/"
extension=mysql.so
```

HTH

C.